# upload to Cloudinary using REST API in CN1

Tags: rest, codenameone, cloudinary

I am trying to upload my pictures to Cloudinary using their REST API. The Cloudinary library from CN1 worked very well for me, but I am looking to control a few things like FailSilently and being able to addToQueue and addToQueueAndWait.

This is my code, where I take a picture using the camera and then I upload to Cloudinary, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
@Override
protected void onMain_ButtonSubirAPIAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    String picture = Capture.capturePhoto(width, -1);
    if(picture!=null){
        String cloudinaryURL = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/"+CLOUDNAME+"/image/upload";
        MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest() {
           protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException  {
              JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
              Map <String, Object> result = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
              labelX.setText((String)result.get("url"));
           }
        };

        request.setPost(true);
        request.setHttpMethod("POST");
        String encoded = Base64.encodeNoNewline((APIKEY + ":" + APISECRET).getBytes());
        request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        request.setUrl(cloudinaryURL);
        try {
            request.addData("file", picture, "image/jpeg");
            request.addArgument("public_id", "name1");
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
        } catch(Exception err) {
        }
    }
}
```

I have been trying to modify parameters indicated from their API documentation page: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#usage_examples

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Here is the syntax:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some changes you need to do in your code.
Please see [this section](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_api).

The `api_key` and `api_secret` shouldn't be added as `APIKEY + ":" + APISECRET` like you did. This syntax is used only when using the Admin API, not Upload API.

At the request parameters:

- You should include the `api_key` parameter set to your api_key.
- You should include the `timestamp` parameter set to the current time.
- This `timestamp`, along with the `public_id` and your `api_secret` [should be signed](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#creating_api_authentication_signatures). This should be the value of the `signature` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The "@" notation is used for browsers and shouldn't be used for request. You need to use basic authentication as such:

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeNoNewline((APIKEY + ":" + APISECRET).getBytes());
request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

Comment: Hi Shai. I just added your lines, but I still get a "400 BAD REQUEST" message. Do you think the addData() and addArgument() methods are being used correctly?

Comment: You did remove the @ portion right? The link you provided isn't for the upload API section but I think the URL should include the image name although that's a bit unclear.

Comment: Yes, I removed the @. Please see the code. I just updated it. I also added a screenshot of the syntax (URL and parameters). I am assuming I have to add the "public_id" (name of the uploaded picture) using the addArgument() method and the path using the addData()